ASP.NET MVC : form is null when posting to controller
I have a very simple page with a very simple model and I'm not entirely sure why when I post the model it's null. I'm looking for a bit of assistance, I've now been staring at this code for 2 hours and I must be over looking something. Also, when the Model.State is not valid, the url changes to not having my Id.
Here is the controller:
using Stonks.Model;
using Stonks.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace StockCenter.Controllers
{
    public class TradeIdeaController : Controller
    {
        // GET: TradeIdea
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Create(int Id)
        {
            //var dailyOptionRecord = new OptionHeaderService().GetById(Id);
            var model = new Models.CreateTradeIdeaModel();
            model.Ticker = "something";
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Models.CreateTradeIdeaModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var newIdea = new TradeIdea()
                {
                    CreatedBy = "StockCenter",
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    LastUpdateBy = "StockCenter",
                    LastUpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    DiscoveryDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    ExpirationDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(14),
                    Ticker = model.Ticker,
                    TradeDescription = model.TradeDescription,
                    TradeDirection = model.TradeDirection
                };

                new TradeIdeaService().Insert(newIdea);

                //return View(model);
                return Content(@"<body>
                       <script type='text/javascript'>
                         window.close();
                       </script>
                     </body> ");
            }

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}

This is the model class:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace StockCenter.Models
{
    public class CreateTradeIdeaModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Ticker { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string TradeDirection { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string TradeDescription { get; set; }
    }
}

And here is the page:
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model StockCenter.Models.CreateTradeIdeaModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "TradeIdea", FormMethod.Post))
{
    // Form Elements here\
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                @Html.Label("Ticker:")
                @Html.TextBox("Ticker_Box",Model.Ticker)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                @Html.Label("TradeDirection:")
                @Html.TextBox("Trade_Direction")
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                @Html.Label("TradeDescription:")
                @Html.TextBox("Trade_Description")
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Idea" id="btnSubmit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}


Have you checked the brower console while sending request to controller? Are the data sending accordingly?

Besides, if you see your @Html.TextBox("Ticker_Box"), those have the underscore, hence when it renders to <input> element, the name attribute will be name="Ticker_Box". So when you send the form, it will not match with the property in your CreateTradeIdeaModel. The same goes for the other text fields and properties as well.

As mentioned in the comment, you customized the name attribute for the <input> element rendered. And those name attributes are not the same as the properties in your CreateTradeIdeaModel class.
Make sure that the property names are matched with your provided names.
@Html.TextBox("TickerBox",Model.Ticker)

@Html.TextBox("TradeDirection")

@Html.TextBox("TradeDescription")

Or you can work with Html.TextBoxFor() or Html.EditorFor() which the compiler will suggest you choose the property from the model. This works with model binding.
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Ticker)

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TradeDirection)

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TradeDescription)


TextBoxFor seems to work, where TextBox didn't
